# SQL join tables with similar data

Tags: sql, match

I have two tables with business names and addresses. Some business names and addresses are writing in different formats.

```
               Table 1                                    Table 3 
ID  Name                    Address            ID Name                     Address
1   The three brothers      12 main st         1  three brothers           main street
2   central the great       12-13 x str        2  main purpose             milli street
3   main purpose shop       4 milli street     3  the great central        12 x-13 x str
```

I need to match the companies which exists in both table like:

```
tbl1ID  tbl2ID
  1       1
  2       3
  3       2
```

Any idea how can I do this ?

Comment: If you have a specific database implementation you are using that could improve the answers.  For instance SQL Server 2008 R2 has Fuzzy searches. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/11/09/fuzzy-logic-and-regex-come-to-t-sql-in-sql-server-2008-r2-available-now.aspx

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731440/a-good-sql-strategy-for-fuzzy-matching-possible-duplicates-using-sql-server-2005

Answer (score -1):

Try This One

It Can Display Whose Name Which Have Same Name In Both Table

```
Select *from table1,table2 where table1.name = table2.name;
```